# Accessing PageReference method from different class

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, pagereference

I'm a newbie to salesforce.
I have 2 Apex class as follows:

```
public class A {

B bb;

public PageReference save() {

bb = new B();
return bb.pay();
}

}

public class B {

public PageReference pay(){

}

}
```

I would like to return the PageReference method pay() at class B on class A. Is that possible? Or Are there any other way for me to call the pay() method from class A? Cuz right now, when I call the method from save() it won't redirect me to pay()

Thanks to the kind hearted soul!

Comment: This should have worked. I am assuming that you are calling the Save method from a visualforce page. Have you specified that on the action attribute?

Comment: @AAU Hi yes i called the !save from VF page. Yes I use  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="all"> But it doesn't seems to go to the pay() method .. :(

Comment: Actually, this shouldn't work.  This code will not compile even.  You have no return in your **pay()** method.

Comment: Like @dphil said, what are you returning from the pay() method?

Comment: @dhil, Hi is there any other way that I could call this pay() method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're going with this because the code you posted is pretty vague. Maybe you could make this a static method if you are only calling the PageReference exactly after you're instantiating the object. Here's a way to expedite the call of an instance method. This one goes to a new opportunity.

```
public class A
{
  public PageReference save()
  {
    return (new B()).pay();
  }
}

public class B
{
  public PageReference pay()
  {
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/006/e');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the redirect to true and that you don't have a rerender on this ajax call.

Comment: No it doesn't work still..